# Hyperledger Composer's deployment process

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

The Composer's model consists of javascript code, entities, query definitions, and access rules. As I understand, everything becomes some kind of executable code after deployment, since Fabric doesn't have anything like that.

What exactly is happening during the deployment process? Is everything compiled into a sort of bytecode? For example, Composer's transaction functions are somehow becoming a part of the Fabric's Invoke method, but how exactly one maps onto the other?

I am asking because I want to add a capability to Composer to run js-based queries, and they need to be somehow mapped to the Fabric's Query method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to study the architecture of Hyperledger Composer.

What you are looking for is the composer-runtime which interact with the underlaying Fabric.
Check out these slides : 
[link](https://www.slideshare.net/SimonStone8/hyperledger-composer-architecture)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!